# `ip link add ifb0 type ifb` does not work on Docker even with `docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN`

Tags: linux, docker, networking

I'd like to add use `ip link` command to create `type ifb`, but fails like this:

```
$ docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN --rm -it ubuntu:14.04 ip link add ifb0 type ifb
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

(I use `ubuntu:14.04` because it has `ip` (`iproute2`) by default, but my actual environment is `ubuntu:16.04` and it fails as the same messages anyway.)

The official doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ says:

> For interacting with the network stack, instead of using --privileged they should use --cap-add=NET_ADMIN to modify the network interfaces.

```
$ docker run -it --rm  ubuntu:14.04 ip link add dummy0 type dummy

RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted

$ docker run -it --rm --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ubuntu:14.04 ip link add dummy0 type dummy
```

It works; `type dummy` is added with `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN`. But my case fails. `--privileged` does not solve this problem.

How can I fix it? And How can I *debug* it?

---

(added at 2020-06-25)

`docker version`:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:21:11 2020
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Comment: Usually Docker manages containers' network environments directly; you don't (and can't) manually run `ip` and similar commands.  What are you trying to set up?

Comment: I'd like to setup https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/wptagent on a macOS.  It uses some network commands for network shaping. However, Docker on Linux (on VMWare) can call them so I'm using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a restriction of Docker for Mac, because some `ip` commands need specific kernel modules which Docker for Mac's LinuxKit does not have.

`docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN --rm -it ubuntu:14.04 ip link add ifb0 type ifb` works on Ubuntu on VMWare.